# Superscript $\omega$ meaning compact objects?

Tags: reference-request, notation, homological-algebra, triangulated-categories

Let's say $\mathcal{T}$ is a compactly generated triangulated category, e.g. the derived category $D(\mathrm{Solid})$ of solid abelian groups (I'm only using this example since it's where I'm seeing this notation I'm asking about). Then why is its subcategory of compact objects denoted by $\mathcal{T}^{\omega}$ (e.g. $D(\mathrm{Solid})^{\omega}$ in Corollary 6.1(ii) in [this paper](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf)) ? When was this notation first used in the literature ?

Comment: Probably because compact objects are the special case $\kappa=\omega$ of the more general notion of a $\kappa$-compact object, where $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal.